# Css свойство второй кнопки instagram

Tags: javascript, html, css

Крайне странный покажется вопрос, но нужно получить селектор второй кнопки в instagram "Регистрация" https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/

Задаю к примеру таким образом: `button.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF:last-child` , и все равно получаю свойства двух кнопок. 
Однако через javascript `document.getElementsByClassName('sqdOP')[1]` спокойно получаю, но нужно именно через css

Comment: button.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF:last-child не сработает, т.к кнопки вложены в разные блоки. Кнопка Регистрация имеет тип submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last-child` никак не сработает. Он работает для элементов внутри одного родительского.

В js же перебирает все найденные в DOM элементы.

В вашем случае нужно искать разницу между самими элементами, либо их размещением в DOM. Как вариант `[type=submit] {ваши стили}`

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. С type=submit получилось. Подтолкнули к решению)

Comment: пожалуйста. успехов